# Unterminated Regular expression literal in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string-literals

I am using radio_button_tag in my rails application, like

```
<%= radio_button_tag "range", "month",false, :onclick => "#{abc_path(:type => params[:type])}" %>
```

When I give like this in my console I am getting this error:

```
Unterminated Regular Expression literal
```

How to resolve this ?? I was trying to fix this..

Please give some suggestions..

Comment: abc_path(:type => params[:type]) - that function returns?

Answer (score 0):

try this single qoute range

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'range', "month", false, :onclick => "#{abc_path(:type => params[:type])}" %>
```

may be this could help and see the rubyonrails api 
formtaghelper for more help [RubyOnRails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html)

Comment: then most probably the error is in your onclick => regular expression and sorry i am not good in the regular expression otherwise i will do it for you :) remove :type => portion and replace with the object to which u want to bind the onclick

Comment: by the way onclick is javacsript function you have to pass an object to it u can pass an object to it either by 'onClick=> document.getElementById('search')' or by onclick => $('object_id') and you can also pass link to it like this <%= check_box_tag :foo, '1', params[:foo], :onclick =>
remote_function(:url => ...) %>